# How many times did the library fail Hermione?

Tags: harry-potter, continuity, hermione-granger

**Goblet of Fire Chapter 26**

> “There’s a way of doing it!” Hermione said crossly.  “There just has
>   to be!”
>
> She seemed to be taking the library’s lack of useful  information on
>   the subject as a personal insult; it had  never failed her before.

**Half Blood Prince Chapter 18**

> Meanwhile, the Hogwarts library had failed Hermione  for the first
>   time in living memory. She was so  shocked, she even forgot that she
>   was annoyed at  Harry for his trick with the bezoar.

If *Half Blood Prince* was the first time that the library failed Hermione, was the search for a method of breathing underwater in *Goblet of Fire* considered successful? In what sense? And if it was successful why does it say that the library had never failed her before, implying that it failed her now?

Or was *Goblet of Fire* not "in living memory" by the time of *Half Blood Prince*?

(Of course there's also the time in *Philosopher's Stone* that the library failed her when looking for Nicholas Flamel, although perhaps that doesn't count as a failure because she did eventually find him, albeit accidentally).

Comment: This is just a Rowling mistake, nothing more

Comment: I suppose, technically speaking, she never finished the Gillyweed library search - she was interrupted and kidnapped(ish) for the second task. Also, it's unclear if the Gillyweed book Moody planted (via Neville) was from the library or not...if it was then technically the library *did* contain the info, it was just already checked out...

Comment: @DavidS But then the library technically did contain the info about Horcruxes as well, the books were just already checked out (removed by Dumbledore).

Comment: almost every time it was that they simply were looking in the wrong books

Comment: If we say that this comes down to 1+1=1, we can blame JKR not knowing Math.

Comment: @Alex It contained the books at the time Riddle was at the school, but I interpreted Dumbledore's removal of the Horcurux-related books as permanent, and he would have done that many years before Hermione arrived at Hogwarts. I'd say books that have been permanently removed from the library...aren't in the library :P

Comment: The second quote is obviously hyperbolic, as "living memory" literally means "for as long as anyone can remember," and Hermione is simply not old enough for the phrase to apply.  So it must be figurative.

Answer (score 4):

> Hermione emerged from between the bookshelves. She looked irritable and at last seemed ready to talk to them.
>
> “All the copies of Hogwarts, A History have been taken out,” she said,
>   sitting down next to Harry and Ron. “And there’s a two-week waiting
>   list. I wish I hadn’t left my copy at home, but I couldn’t fit it in
>   my trunk with all the Lockhart books.”

I am not sure if this qualifies, because the library did *have* the book, but every copy was taken. However, if you are counting every time she simply failed to get her hands on a library book, then this will work.

Comment: I'd say this counts. Good catch! For completeness' sake, could you cite which book and which chapter this excerpt is from? (I'm guessing from the mention of Lockhart that it's *Chamber of Secrets*, but it can't hurt to be sure.)

Comment: @F1Krazy it is, that takes place when all the students are suddenly interested in learning more about the myth of the Chamber.

Comment: Why didn't she just Accio Book?

Comment: @JAB - Because every book in the library would have immediately hit her in the head

Comment: @Valorum never seemed to be a problem for Harry when he Accio Broomed.

Comment: @JAB - It seems a very imprecise spell

Comment: @Valorum Nah. In fact, in order to Accio to work, you have to focus in a specific object. Accio book won't bring all the books, but only the one that is in your mind.